# Why does this tree display function print only the first element?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, binary-tree

The display function I've used for printing the tree only seems to print the first element and not the rest. I don't know why I suspect the insert function which I've used without recursion might be the cause but can't seem to understand where it goes wrong. Any explanation on how to correct it or where the code fails would be helpful. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void insert(int data_add,struct tree *temp);
void display(struct tree *temp);

struct tree
{
  int data;
  struct tree *left;
  struct tree *right;
} *root = NULL;

int main()
{
  int data_add,n;
  while(1)
  {

    printf("\n\n1.Add\n2.Display\n4.Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    switch(n)
    {
      case 1: printf("\nEnter the element to add ");
              scanf("%d",&data_add);
              insert(data_add,root);
              break;
      case 2: printf("The nos are: ");
              display(root);
              break;

      /*case 3: printf("The nos are: ");
              reversedisplay(root);*/
      case 4: exit(1);
              break;
      default: printf("\nChoose a appropriate option");
    }
  }
}

void insert(int data,struct tree *temp)
{
  struct tree *current;
  current = (struct tree*) malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
  current->data = data;

  if(root == NULL)
  {
    root = current;
    current->left = NULL;
    current->right = NULL;
  }
  else
   {
     while(temp!=NULL)
     {
       if(data<temp->data)
       {
         temp = temp->left;
       }
       else
       {
         temp = temp->right;
       }
     }

     temp = current;
     current->left = NULL;
     current->right = NULL;
   }

}


void display(struct tree *temp)
{
  if(temp == NULL)
  return;

  display(temp->right);
  display(temp->left);

  printf("%d",temp->data);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that while inserting an element you are not assigning the newly inserted element as the left or right child of any other node. You are just traversing the tree while insertion, every time you try to insert the element due to which the new elements are not added in the tree.

Comment: But I've allocated space for current and then after traversal I'm assigning temp to current right? So that doesn't add new elements in the tree? So how to achieve that?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that while inserting a node you are not making the new inserted node as the left or right child of any node, because of which the new node is not actually inserted in your tree.
Your code where things go wrong -

```
temp = current;
 current->left = NULL;
 current->right = NULL;
```

After coming out of the loop, `temp` is NULL , now `current` is assigned to `temp`, but there is no way to reach the new node from any other node in the tree, because it is not left/right child of any node in the tree.
Here I present the correct code for the insert function -

```
void insert(int data,struct tree *temp)
{
   struct tree *current;
   current = (struct tree*) malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
   current->data = data;
   current->left = NULL;
   current->right = NULL;

   if(root == NULL)
   {
     root = current;
     current->left = NULL;
     current->right = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
      struct tree *par=temp; //par is used to keep track of node whose left 
                             //or right  child will be the new node.
      while(temp!=NULL)
      {
         par=temp;
         if(data<temp->data)
         temp=temp->left;
         else temp=temp->right;
      }
      // The below part is used to make the new node as left or right child 
      // of the appropriate node.
      if(data<par->data)
          par->left=current;
      else 
         par->right=current;
   }

}
```

Moreover , slight change in your `display` function, change your `printf` statement to - 
`printf("%d ",temp->data);` .
In previous version all the node values would be printed without no spaces giving an impression that only one number is printed.

Comment: Just one question, the code works great and I understand my mistake also understand what the variable par does over there, but when par and temp are the same thing, how does par still point to the existing tree while temp changes. When pointers are equalled like that don't they simply point to the same place when one changes ? I know a noob question maybe but please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `insert` function. You never link the new node to the old one. You would need to use pointers keep the address of the right or left node. Instead of that, you only copy the address of current node in the local temp variable. You code should be:

```
  ... 
  else
   {
     t = &temp;
     while(*t!=NULL)
     {
       if(data<(*t)->data)
       {
         t = &(*t)->left;
       }
       else
       {
         t = &(*t)->right;
       }
     }

     *t = current;  // actually copy current in right of left of last node
     current->left = NULL;
     current->right = NULL;
   }
```

But that's not all, in order to display the elements in order, you should change display to:

```
void display(struct tree *temp)
{
  if(temp == NULL)
  return;

  display(temp->left);      // left side first
  printf("%d",temp->data);  // then current
  display(temp->right);     // finally right side
}
```